# How to regenerate /etc/init.d/.depend.(boot|start|stop) on Debian?

Tags: debian, init.d, sysvinit

Suppose one deleted the following files.

```
/etc/init.d/.depend.boot
/etc/init.d/.depend.start
/etc/init.d/.depend.stop
```

How to regenerate them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good question. The only reference I've found to those files is in `man insserv`:

```
   /etc/init.d/.depend.boot,
   /etc/init.d/.depend.start,
   /etc/init.d/.depend.stop
          The make(1) like dependency files produced by  insserv  for  booting,
          starting, and stopping with the help of startpar(8).
```

And in fact, running just plain `insserv` touches their modification time.  So try that and see if it rebuilds them.

As a tip, when you are tempted to delete something like this for whatever reason, move them to a temporary trash directory instead.

Comment: `insserv` regenerated them.

Answer (score 0):

find the package it come from and excecute something like :

```
dpkg --reinstall package name
```

or

```
dpkg-reconfigure package name
```

I'm not sure but that how I would do.
To find what package create what file you can use:

```
dpkg --search .depend.start
```

Thos file seems to be generated by the package `insserv` so  command line according to [this blog](http://www.goatpr0n.de/blog/2008/04/09.speed.up.debian.boot.process.using.start.par) and the man page:

```
dpkg-reconfigure insserv
```

Should fix the problem, but **BE CAREFULL THIS CAN BREAK THE BOOT SEQUENCE**

Comment: They are not associated with any package on my Debian system.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that those files are system-wise not package-wise? This simply _cannot_ work, as I understand it, they contain information from _many packages_!

Comment: @tohecz This is obvious that those script came from somthing and more likely a package as they are not on my debian and more over when I read those kind of thing http://www.goatpr0n.de/blog/2008/04/09.speed.up.debian.boot.process.using.start.par

Comment: @JosephR. do you have them install ?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @tohecz on this. These scripts are generated based on the services you have installed. They do not depend on a single package.

Comment: I don't think you have to re-install / re-configure `insserv`, you just have to run it (see my answer).

Comment: @goldilocks yes in fact it should be OK too

Comment: There is no such `dpkg --reinstall` option.